# Can anyone help me understand the meaning of "crystallized thought"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I want to get the meaning of the following sentence:

> if a program is crystallized thought, ...

Does it mean a well-planned program or well-made one?

Thanks

Comment: Liquids and gasses don't have inherent shape. When they crystallize they finally get a shape of their own.

Comment: This analogy is similar, in some ways, to the quote "I call architecture frozen music" usually attributed to the 17th century composer Johann Gottfried von Goethe. In both cases a more concrete product is contrasted with something more abstract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither. It is a metaphor meant to describe programs in general, not describing or referring to a particular program, or even a particular kind of program.

The metaphor imagines "thought" as being like something dissolved in a fluid, that gradually crystallises out into a solid, structured mass, and the program as the resulting mass.

Comment: Do you mean, the program that has been structured naturally or thought gradually?

Comment: @eMehran: You'll have to ask the writer what they intended by the metaphor. But I take it it refers to the structuring.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I got it. I'm translating the text so I'm looking for the best understanding.